# Replace variables between curly braces with a dynamic component in angular

Tags: regex, angular, factory

I'm receiving data from a server containing HTML with variables included.

exemple of data:
`content = '<div> I can be displayed here {{variable1}} or here {{variable2}} or any wherelse  </div>'`

I want to replace {{variable1}} and {{variable2}} with dynamic components in angular upon received from server.
these variables dont have fixed place nor fixed number.

I created a stackblitz where i can find these variables, create the dynamic component but i can't place them in the right place.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcxutx

Comment: Use a string replace with callback `text.replace( /{{(.+?)}}/g, function( m, g1 ) { return hash[g1]; } ); ` or like this

Comment: i didn't get it. i need to replace it by a hole component because in that compoent there is a bunch of data and events. see the stackblitz

Comment: The replacement is done on the 'example of data' string above before you eval it or run it. Yes ?

Comment: in the [stackblitz exemple](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcxutx) the exemple data is what i receive from the server. i'm going to display it in a contenteditable div ( in it's innerHTML). but what i want to display is the component instead of the variable received from the server ( what is betwwen curly blaces). just for info, i dont know how many variable are there and their place is not fixed.

Comment: on the stackblitz the process is shown by clicking on the test button. but in the real app it must be replaced upon data received. I'm using a foctory to create the component because the component has a click event included. i'm open to any other solution. the most important is that it replace the variables with it's components in the right place.

Comment: any help for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna evaluate a string that came from your backend as an angular expression - which is not a good solution, but in a real world there a bunch of complicated problems - I'm not your jude )

So you have to use $interpolate service here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: I'm not using angularJS i'm using angular 9. in the satckblitz i provided, when you click on the button, there are 2 components that are created. i want them to replace the variables between curly braces. these components have events too so it's not just a text replacement. in the stackblitz, i can't figure it out how to put these 2 new components in the right place.

Comment: just for info: the {{var}} is just a variable it's not meant to be an angular expression it could be [[var]] or ((var)) it's just a variable that can be detecter with regex not more.

Comment: Okay, let me get into stackblitz example

Comment: What about this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader ?

Comment: the problem is always the same because the dynamic part is inside the received data.

Comment: Is it possible to include the dynamic reference inside the received data from the server (where the variabe are exactly placed).

Comment: any help for this question?